# jQuery treeTable Plugin throwing error "TypeError: $(...).treetable is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jqtree

**Scenario:** Consider the following in code html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery treetable</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/screen.css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.treetable.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.treetable.theme.default.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <table id="tree">
                <tr id="node-1">
                    <td>Parent</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="node-2" class="child-of-node-1">
                    <td>Child</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="node-3" class="child-of-node-2">
                    <td>Child</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.treetable.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#tree").treetable({ expandable: true }); 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

All the resources/dependencies (js, css and image files) are loads perfectly with 200 HTTP Status (later on 304).

**Issue:** Is error in Firebug. Below is the error from firebug console:

```
TypeError: $(...).treetable is not a function
[Break On This Error] 
$("#tree").treetable({ expandable: true });
```

**Links:**

1. [Sources for plugin](https://github.com/ludo/jquery-treetable)
2. [Documentation and Demo/Examples](http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-plugins/treeTable/doc/index.html)

**Question:** Does anyone got this issue & knows any solution? Then please put some light on this it will be of great help.

---

**Update 1:** Even tried with following code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tree").treetable({ expandable: true });
    });
</script>
```

---

**Update 2:** Based on all the answers.

I tried with following code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tree").treeTable({ expandable: true });
    });
</script>
```

But no luck :-(

And is the source example its just 't' not capital 'T'.([Link](https://github.com/ludo/jquery-treetable/blob/master/index.html#L857))

Comment: *"And is the source example its just 't' not capital 'T'"* And yet the documentation is quite clear about it: `$("#your_table_id").treeTable();`. Perhaps the plug-in has issues.

Comment: Got it, please see the answer. Issue was in documentation.. Thanks for your time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old reference provided in the documentation & installation steps ([link > 2.2](http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-plugins/treeTable/doc/index.html))

2.2 step says that "Add [src/javascripts/jquery.treeTable.js](http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-plugins/treeTable/src/javascripts/jquery.treeTable.js)"

But it does not work and the working sample referring to different `jquery.treeTable.js` file on the server. Its correct in the [GitHub scource code](https://github.com/ludo/jquery-treetable/blob/master/javascripts/src/jquery.treetable.js)

Other answers referred to code `treetable()` has to be like `treeTable()`. But it didn't work. :-(

**Issue was :** 2.2 step says that "Add [src/javascripts/jquery.treeTable.js](http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-plugins/treeTable/src/javascripts/jquery.treeTable.js)"

**Solution:** Get the `jquery.treeTable.js` file from [GitHub](https://github.com/ludo/jquery-treetable/blob/master/javascripts/src/jquery.treetable.js)

[Issue Raised on GitHub](https://github.com/ludo/jquery-treetable/issues/53)

Comment: Got it, please see the answer. Issue was in documentation.. Thanks for your time..

Comment: Probably worth dropping the maintainer a note. (Absolutely ***nuts*** to change it from `treeTable` to `treetable`.)

Answer (score 0):

your methods is wrong. [Check the Docs for example](https://github.com/ludo/jquery-treetable/blob/master/index.html). you need to use the lowercase for the method.

```
 $("#tree").treetable({ expandable: true });
```

Comment: Updated my question: I used both `treetable()` as well as `treeTable()`, no luck :-(

Comment: Got it, please see the answer. Issue was in documentation.. Thanks for your time..